# How to Store/Copy List or ArrayList to HashTable ? in C#

Tags: c#, .net, list

i have a program in which list/ArrayList will be populated at run time and it can be of any size (but it is of specific datatype). i want to copy all the "values" of list/ArrayList to the HashTable.

or i can convert that list/ArrayList to array and then copy to HashTable?

Comment: Where do the keys come from? Please add any code you have.

Comment: in previous handling keys are coming from another class's enum, but in the above case i don't know at compile time how many values can be in List so i can't make keys in that class.

Comment: yOU SHOULD PROVIDE CODES THAT YOU TRIED SO FAR

Comment: this is the code
Class1.HashTable1.Add(HashkeyClass.HashKeyenum.enumname, valueFromMethod);

Comment: ArrayList? Hashtable? It's 2018, not 2004. Use an Array or generic List and then use the `.Dictionary()` extension method to get a generic `Dictionary`. Don't use those prehistoric classes, they have been obsolete for 11 years now.

Comment: @nvoigt there are some restrictions in the architecture

Comment: @nvoigt you are unable to get my point

Comment: Your point is that you are working with code that has not been refactored for longer than a decade. My point was to point that out in case you did not know. It's hard to tell whether you *know* there are better ways today.

Comment: I HAVE GOT THE ANSWER BY MY OWN, PLEASE DON'T WASTE TIME TO ANSWER THIS QUESTION.

Comment: SIMPLY,
HashTable1.Add(assignAnyKey, List),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call this function after you populated the ArrayList:

```
public Hashtable function(ArrayList aList)
{
    Hashtable hTable = new Hashtable();        
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var item in aList)
    {
        if (!hTable.Contains(item))
            hTable.Add(i,item);
        i++;
    }
    return hTable;
}
```

It should also work with List

Comment: That's fine (y) . Thanks but i have got another solution